# Dynamically creating type alias

Tags: c++, types, alias, type-alias

Having a type alias

```
using MyVariantType = std::variant<int, double, std::string, bool>;
```

and an alias template,

```
template <typename T>
using MyFunctionType = std::function<bool(T)>
```

how can I dynamically create a the following type alias from both `MyVariantType` and `MyFunctionType`?

```
using MyFunctionVariantType = std::variant<MyFunctionType<int>, MyFunctionType<double>, MyFunctionType<std::string>, MyFunctionType<bool>>
```

Comment: I swear I answered something similar to this in the last 30 days, but I can't find it.

Answer (score 0):

This snippet will take each type from the variant and will create a variant of `MyFunctionType`'s instead. It works with template specialization to figure out the types of the variant:

```
#include <variant>
#include <functional>

using MyVariantType = std::variant<int, double>;

template <typename T>
using MyFunctionType = std::function<bool(T)>;

/// Helper struct to create the FunctionType from the Varaint Type
template <typename T>
struct CreateFunctionVariant;
template <typename... Ts>
struct CreateFunctionVariant<std::variant<Ts...>>
{
    using Type = std::variant<MyFunctionType<Ts>...>;
};
using MyFunctionVariantType = CreateFunctionVariant<MyVariantType>::Type;

/// Make sure it actually produces the right type
static_assert(std::is_same_v<MyFunctionVariantType, std::variant<MyFunctionType<int>, MyFunctionType<double>>>);
```